# Date in WPF listbox not displaying in correct locale

Tags: wpf

I have a XAML page with a ListBox bound to a collection of Customer objects. The Customer class has a CreatedDate property which is bound to a TextBox within the ListBoxItem template. For some reason the date is appearing in US format (I'm in the UK), despite adding this known fix to App.xaml:-

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
   typeof(FrameworkElement),
   new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

Dates elsewhere on the page are being formatted correctly. Any ideas?

**Update:-** the date in the ListBoxItem template is being displayed like this:-

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <Run Text="{Binding CreatedDate}"/>
        ...various other <Run elements ...
    </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

This seems to be where the problem lies. If I bind the CreatedDate using a plain  instead of in the  construct (i.e. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding CreatedDate}"/>`), it formats correctly. Why would this be? Is it a bug with the Inlines element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has also been reported to be a bug in the [Microsoft Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wpf/thread/1ec9d115-b119-41b2-8f80-223a71a79457) (although there is no link to a bug report).  Per Mike Danes, a moderator in the forum:

```
The problem is the Run element, this is not a FrameworkElement,
it's a FrameworkContentElement. 
Its language property was registered with a default value of en-US 
and it cannot be overriden.
```

In the meantime, you could work around this by setting the language right on the run (this is suggested in the MS forum, but I have not tried it myself).

Another alternative, if you know that you alsways want a specific format, is to use the StringFormat option in the binding:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <Run Text="{Binding CreatedDate, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}}"/>
        ...various other <Run elements ...
    </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

Note that the StringFormat option for ShortDate does not work - you need to put in an explicit format:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <Run Text="{Binding CreatedDate, StringFormat=d}"/>
        ...various other <Run elements ...
    </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```